# django-pyodbc-azure DatabaseError: ('42000', '[42000] Error converting data type nvarchar to int

Tags: python, django, azure, pyodbc, django-pyodbc-azure

I am a beginner at backend. Trying to test web services on my windows machine.

On the linux server i have a working machine with following database settings :

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django_pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'database_name',
    'USER': 'user@server_name',
    'PASSWORD': 'pass',
    'HOST': 'host',
    'PORT': '1433',
    'OPTIONS': {
        'driver': 'FreeTDS',
    }
},
```

I want to locally run the web services on my windows pc before commiting anything to git. To do this, i am using django-pyodbc-azure 1.0.10 which is provided here :

https://github.com/michiya/django-pyodbc-azure/tree/dd87bd3379475ff596210a9243c04c01add0be4d

On my local windows pc

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'sql_server.pyodbc',
    'NAME': 'database_name',
    'USER': 'user@server_name',
    'PASSWORD': 'pass',
    'HOST': 'server_name.database.windows.net',
    'PORT': '',
    'OPTIONS': {
            'driver': 'SQL Server Native Client 11.0',
            'MARS_Connection': True,
    }
},
```

I changed my settings accordingly but it gives the following error :

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sql_server\pyodbc\base.py", line 396, in execute
raise utils.DatabaseError(*e.args)

DatabaseError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL     Server]Error converting data type nvarchar to int. (8114) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

I guess it connects the database but it creates a convertion error.

I am using postman to post the service using

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/GetFixture
```

It raises 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. But this service is workinh fine on linux server.

Answer (score 0):

I use django-pyodbc rather than django-pyodbc-azure, however, it is a fork. I believe you just need to add this to your options on the Linux side:

```
'OPTIONS': {
    'host_is_server': True,
    'autocommit': True,
    'unicode_results': True,
    'extra_params': 'tds_version=8.0'
},
```

On the windows machine, just be sure to include:

```
'host_is_server': True,
'autocommit': True,
'unicode_results': True,
```

Also note, HOST takes this form:

```
'HOST': 'database.domain.com,1433',
```

...where 1433 is the port SQL Server is running on.
The autocommit is required for Django 1.6+.

Comment: i still have this issue. FlipperPA can you help?

Comment: I've actually switched to django-pyodbc-azure lately. That said, what stack are you using and what Linux flavor? Ubuntu + unixODBC + FreeTDS + pyodbc underneath?

Comment: Got it fixed a few minutes after i asked this question. I had to add some dsn settings and it did the trick. I will write a blog about how I made it work with my current environment :) Which was Ubuntu + unixODBC + FreeTDS + pyodbc